# Integrating the same integral in two ways

Tags: calculus, integration, contour-integration

I need to calculate the integral of $\int_{-1}^{+1}|z| dz$ in two ways:

1. integrating along a line
2. integrating along the arc of unit radius circle

However, I have some trouble coming to the right answer and am somewhat confused because these two methods give two different answers.

Here's my attempt:

For one, I tried to apply the definition $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and interpreting it on $xy$ plane with such $y=0$ and $|z|=|x|$, but the answer I am getting is $0$, which is apparently incorrect.

For two, I define $|z|=re^{i\theta}$ and $dz=ie^{i\theta}d\theta$, but I am confused about the upper and lower bounds of integration, since apparently from $0$ to $2\pi$ is incorrect.

I'd very much appreciate if someone could explain how to continue solving this problem based on the ideas that I've mentioned, and explain why these answers differ.

Comment: Integrating from $0$ to $2\pi$ would take you all of the way around the unit circle, no?  Don't you want to only go *half way* around the unit circle?  I would also be interested to know how you got $\int_{-1}^{1} |x| \,\mathrm{d}x = 0$ (your first method).

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thank you for answering, sure. I pretty much thought of it as $\int_{-1}^{1}|z|dz=\int_{-1}^{0}-z dz+\int_{0}^{1}z dz = -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=0$. I am sure I made a mistake somewhere here but I am not sure. On the second question, am I correct in interpreting that I should change the bounds from $0$ to $\pi$?

Comment: Typo in $|z|=re^{i\theta}$? How is $\int_{-1}^0 x\,dx = 1/2$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Could you please elaborate on what you mean by the typo and $1/2$? I am not sure I understood.

Comment: $\int_{-1/2}^{0} -z\,\mathrm{d}z = -1/2$???

Comment: Yes, that's indeed a typo I made, therefore my solution is incorrect. What @Ted Shifrin do you mean about $|z|$, though?

Comment: $z=re^{i\theta}$, and so $|z|=$ what? Your formula for $dz$ is correct since you're on $|z|=1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin So, based on everything, am I understanding this correctly that $\int_{-1}^{1}|z|dz=\int_{0}^{\pi}ie^{i\theta} d\theta$, if $|z|=1$?

Comment: Which is just $\int_C dz$.

Comment: @TedShifrin But how do I find this integral? Is this a contour integral? If yes, then I need only half way around the circle.

Comment: @TedShifrin I get $-2$ as the final answer. Is this alright, or should it be $2$ instead?

Comment: The answer is $2$. You’re going from $-1$ to $1$ — we’re not sure whether the path is the upper semicircle or the lower. So $\theta$ goes either from $\pi$ to $0$ or from $\pi$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: As for why the integrals differ, that is because the function you are integrating is not conservative. There is no theorem that says arbitrary functions integrated along different paths between the same endpoints will give the same results. Functions that have this property form a very special class. Complex analytic functions are famously part of that class, but this function is not one of them. It is not even a complex function, because its values are strictly real.